# Quotient $G/N$ of solvable group $G$ is solvable. Is my (trivial) proof correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, quotient-group, solvable-groups

I'd like some feedback from experts in group theory.

Let $N \trianglelefteq G$, $G$ solvable. Then $G/N$ is solvable.

My proof: Take canonical homomorphism $G \rightarrow G/N$ ($x \rightarrow xN$) and let abelian tower $\{e\} = G_0 \trianglelefteq \ldots \trianglelefteq G_m = G $. Image of normal group under **surjective** homomorphism is normal, thus we have a tower $N = f(G_0) \trianglelefteq \ldots \trianglelefteq f(G_m) = G/N$. By one of isomorphism theorems, $G_{i+1} / G_i\cong G_{i+1} / N / G_i / N$, thus tower is abelian.

Where did I go wrong? And if I am correct, why is "standard proof" using more complicating structures such as $G_iN/N$?

Edit: I know that $G_i/N$ only makes sense for $N \subset G_i$. But for those $i$ such that $G_i \subset N$, canonical homomorphism gives $f(G_i)=N$ (collapse) so the whole thing still stands, i.e. we have this tower

$$N \trianglelefteq \cdots \trianglelefteq N \trianglelefteq G_{i+1}/N\trianglelefteq \cdots \trianglelefteq G_m/N = G/N$$

Comment: What is your $f$. If $f$ means the canonical homomorphism $G\rightarrow G/N$, then it doesn't make sense that $f(G_0) = N$.

Comment: That’s because (I think) $G_{i+1}/G_{i}$ has no reason to be isomorphic to $(G_{i+1}/N)/(G_{i}/N)$, unless (eg) $N \subset G_{i}$. Indeed, how would you even define $G_i/N$ otherwise?

Comment: I wrote it, $x \rightarrow xN$ is canonical homorphism. $f(e) = N$. So this is also a subgroup, right? I don't see the problem. I think $G_i/N$ is well-defined?

Comment: Compare also with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967218/if-g-is-solvable-and-h-trianglelefteq-g-then-g-h-is-solvable?rq=1).

Comment: $G_i/N$ only makes sense if $N\subseteq G_i$. Otherwise, you need to take $G_iN/N$, but then your quotients are not what you want: you get $G_{i+1}N/G_{i}N$, so you still have work to do.

Comment: Remember that the notation $K/N$ is only used when $N$ is a subgroup of $K$. If $G_i$ does not contain $N$, then you can't use the Isomorphism Theorem that says that $(G/M)/(N/M)\cong G/N$ when $N\triangleleft G$, $M\triangleleft G$, and $M\leq N\leq G$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edited the post, please check the update. I know that doesn't make sense, but canonical homomorphism collapses these groups in identity $N$, i.e. $f(G_i) = N$ for $G_i \subset N$. So I apply the above isomorphism theorem only for those $i$ such that $N\subset G_i$

Comment: You seem to think that the only possibilities are $G_i\subseteq N$ or $N\subseteq G_i$. That's not true. Consider $G=C_2\times C_2$, $N=C_2\times\{e\}$, and your normal series being $\{e\}\times\{e\}\leq \langle (x,x)\rangle \leq G$.

Comment: The problem is that the $G_i$ may fail to either contain $N$ *or* be contained in $N$. Again $f(G_i) = G_iN/N$, which is equal to $G_i/N$ only if $N\leq G_i$.